# Valgrind - Open Windows memory dump

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, crash-dumps, memory-dump

I have a memory leak on a service installed on a Windows productive server where I can't stop service or install programs. I used the task manager to extract a dump of the memory to a file.

This memory dump make more that 1GB, but when I use tools like DotMemory, they see only 2MB of memory. I think that the leak is in unmanaged memory and want to open the dump with Valgrind to find the leak, but I could not find how to open a dump using Valgrind.

Please notice that it's almost the first time that I use Valgrind, I'm really not familiar with this program. I don't know if it is possible or if it even make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is not available on Windows, except for some old ports that I don't believe are maintained. Additionally, I'm not aware of it having any memory dump analysis features.

I'm not too familiar with Windows tools. The nearest equivalent to Valgrind is IBM Rational PurifyPlus, but I believe that there are others like BoundsChecker and Insure++. These are likely to require an instrumentation step, which wouldn't be compatible with your live server requirement.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Valgrind not being available for Windows is not a problem. I can transfer the dump file to a Linux machine and analyse it here.

Comment: I still don't think that will help.